# Call a list of string from another files in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a list of String in my file that actually is called in the same file, what I want to do is to move this List of String and move from another file creating a class, because I need to call these Strings from others files.
What will be the best options?
THis is my code:

```
class CmCategoryList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CmCategoryListState createState() => _CmCategoryListState();
}

class _CmCategoryListState extends State<CmCategoryList> {
  List<String> names = <String>['Bellezza', 'Moda', 'Capelli', 'Estetica', 'Soldi', 'Finanza', 'Contabilità', 'Viaggi'];



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        itemCount: names.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            width: 100,
            child: Card(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
              color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,

              child: Center(
                  child: Text('${names[index]}',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15,fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,color: Colors.white),
                  )
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
    );
  }
}
```

as you can see the List is called on the method _CmCategoryListState, I want to remove this and move such List to another file and call it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to go in my opinion is to create a new file called resources.dart

```
class Resources {
    static final List<String> NAMES = ['Bellezza', 'Moda', 'Capelli', 'Estetica', 'Soldi', 'Finanza', 'Contabilità', 'Viaggi'];
}
```

This is assuming your list never changes.

Wherever you want to use this list, just

```
import 'resources.dart'; // In the file you want

Resources.NAMES; // Like this, you can access the list
```

There are other approaches but I find this better because I know exactly in which file I have the list so that I can make changes later if required.